# how to add an color picker control to highchart for changing the color of series by user

Tags: highcharts

find  here  my doubt:   https://jsfiddle.net/rur3wthp/`

```
Function() for getting the color value from color picker and apply the same to line series dynamically
```

`
How can I apply the color picker color to the series in the chart.
Thanks in advance I searched all websites I cannot find the clear solution as I m beginner help me out.

Comment: use update method from highcharts api.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `series.update()` method from highcharts api we can update all the series options. Here we in our case it is color aspect of the series.

you can simply do

```
chart.series[identifier].update({
    color: "#ff0000"
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle to update 2 different series: https://jsfiddle.net/vh27mcL2/

Here is the api ref for the update method : https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update